# Evitar abrir un link en una pestaña nueva (ya sea con scroll click o click derecho abrir en una pestaña nueva)

Tags: javascript

Tengo una serie de links de diferentes productos, al darles click despliegan un modal, pero al abrirlos en una pestaña nueva pierden el estilo CSS. Quiero evitar que el usuario pueda abrir estos links en una pestaña nueva ya sea mediante el scroll click o click derecho y abrir en una nueva pestaña.

Intente esto pero solo funciona con el `alert`, necesito que no muestre ninguna alerta:

```
document.onmousedown = disableClick

function disableClick(e) {
    if (e.which == 2) {
        alert("You can't do this") //Funciona
        return false
    } else if (e.which == 3) {
        //alert("You can't do this") //No funciona
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes colocar el código del link que abre el modal?

Comment: ¡No olvides aceptar tu respuesta! El bot _Comunidad_ [relanzó tu pregunta al inicio](/posts/339077/timeline).

Comment: ¡Y el bot lo volvió a relanzar!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré una solución.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    //Disable part of page
    jQuery("clase-o-id-donde-desahbilitar-click-derecho").on("contextmenu",function(e){
        return false;
    });
});

jQuery(document).on('auxclick', 'clase-o-id-donde-desahbilitar-scroll-click', function (e) {
    if (e.which === 2) { //middle Click 
          return false;
    }
    return true;
});
```

Comment: Una explicación a tu script no caería mal

Comment: Que bien, buena solución, estas desactivando ciertas teclas. Aún te falta desactivar una si, probaste presionando ctrl + clic en el enlace ? la combinación ctrl + clic en cualquier enlace te abre por obligación en otra ventana.

Comment: si, también funciona con ctrl + clic

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre lo siguiente:

Supongamos que tenemos los siguientes link

```
<a href="producto1.php">Producto 1</a>
<a href="producto2.php">Producto 2</a>
<a href="producto3.php">Producto 3</a>
```

Con una función en javascript, vamos redireccionar al modal, por ende eliminar la etiqueta href.

```
<a onclick("producto1.php")>Producto 1</a>
<a onclick("producto2.php")>Producto 2</a>
<a onclick("producto3.php")>Producto 3</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function link_modal(url){
        window.location.href = url;
    }
</script>
```

Esto forzara al usuario que solamente al hacer click te lleve al modal en la misma pagina.